# VSCode Mac: How to restore top menu bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There has never been a top menu bar showing 'File', 'View', etc on my version of VSCode for some reason.
Does anyone have any suggestions? Nothing in the threads about this issue works for me.

['View: Toggle Menu' doesn't show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W88mR.png)

[What my work space looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uewN.png)

I followed other troubleshooting threads suggesting exiting full screen mode, moving my cursor to the top, updating my system, searching for 'View: Toggle Menu Bar' on my command palette and nothing comes up.

Answer (score 0):

`Window: Title Bar Style` is what you're looking for, just change it from `custom` to `native`.